# Run two functions by command button

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to run a code through a command button as the below code : I have two functions and I need the code to run successively through them, while I got the below error

> TypeError: load_data() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'Selected_City', 'Selected_Month', and 'Selected_Day'

```
CITY_DATA = { 'chicago': 'chicago.csv',
              'new york city': 'new_york_city.csv',
              'washington': 'washington.csv' }
def enter_data():
    Selected_City=City_selection_combobox.get()
    Selected_Month=Month_selection_combobox.get()
    Selected_Day=Day_selection_combobox.get()
    return Selected_City, Selected_Month, Selected_Day
def load_data (Selected_City,Selected_Month,Selected_Day):
    df=pd.read_csv() ### Here  insert the file location !!!! 
    df['Start Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
    df['month']= df['Start Time'].dt.month
    df['day_of_week']=df['Start Time'].dt.day_name()
    if Selected_Month != 'All':
        months=['January' ,'February','March','April','May','June']
        Selected_Month = months.index(Selected_Month)+1
        df=df[df['month']==Selected_Month]
    else: 
        df['month']=df['Start Time'].dt.Selected_Month
    if Selected_Day !='All':
        df=df[df['day_of_week']==Selected_Day.title()]
    else: 
        df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.day_name()
        return df 

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Data Entry Form")
frame=tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

User_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame,text="user information")
User_info_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=10)

City_selection_title = tkinter.Label(User_info_frame,text="Please select the city")
City_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(User_info_frame,values=['chicago','new york city','washington'])
City_selection_title.grid(column=0,row=0)
City_selection_combobox.grid(column=0,row=1)

Month_selection_title = tkinter.Label(User_info_frame,text="Please filter by Month")
Month_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(User_info_frame,values=['All' , 'January' , 'February','March','April','May','June'])
Month_selection_title.grid(column=1,row=0)
Month_selection_combobox.grid(column=1,row=1)

Day_selection_title =tkinter.Label(User_info_frame,text="Please select the required day")
Day_selection_combobox =ttk.Combobox(User_info_frame,values=['All' , 'Sunday' , 'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'])
Day_selection_title.grid(column=2,row=0)
Day_selection_combobox.grid(column=2,row=1)

Submit_button=tkinter.Button(frame,text='Submit',command= lambda:[enter_data(),load_data])
Submit_button.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='news',padx=20,pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using `lambda: load_data(*enter_data())` - if you don't know what the * does, look at python args and kwargs. Also in `load_data`, you should do something with the `df` and not just return it.

Comment: @TheLizzard That should be an answer.

Comment: @Barmar an answer would require a proper explanation. I didn't have the time to write a proper answer so I left a comment to see if I can get OP on the correct path. Feel free to write an answer yourself and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue description**:

So you are calling a function with 2 arguments that accepts 3 arguments, try my code through this you will get pass the error you are facing:

**Solution:**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

CITY_DATA = { 'chicago': 'chicago.csv',
              'new york city': 'new_york_city.csv',
              'washington': 'washington.csv' }

def load_data(Selected_City,Selected_Month,Selected_Day):
    df=pd.read_csv()
    df['Start Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
    df['month']= df['Start Time'].dt.month
    df['day_of_week']=df['Start Time'].dt.day_name()
    if Selected_Month != 'All':
        months=['January' ,'February','March','April','May','June']
        Selected_Month = months.index(Selected_Month)+1
        df=df[df['month']==Selected_Month]
    else: 
        df['month']=df['Start Time'].dt.Selected_Month
    if Selected_Day !='All':
        df=df[df['day_of_week']==Selected_Day.title()]
    else: 
        df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.day_name()
        return df 

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Data Entry Form")
frame=tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

User_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame,text="user information")
User_info_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=10)

City_selection_title = tkinter.Label(User_info_frame,text="Please select the city")
City_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(User_info_frame,values=['chicago','new york city','washington'])
City_selection_title.grid(column=0,row=0)
City_selection_combobox.grid(column=0,row=1)

Month_selection_title = tkinter.Label(User_info_frame,text="Please filter by Month")
Month_selection_combobox = ttk.Combobox(User_info_frame,values=['All' , 'January' , 'February','March','April','May','June'])
Month_selection_title.grid(column=1,row=0)
Month_selection_combobox.grid(column=1,row=1)

Day_selection_title =tkinter.Label(User_info_frame,text="Please select the required day")
Day_selection_combobox =ttk.Combobox(User_info_frame,values=['All' , 'Sunday' , 'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'])
Day_selection_title.grid(column=2,row=0)
Day_selection_combobox.grid(column=2,row=1)

def selection():
    Selected_City=City_selection_combobox.get()
    Selected_Month=Month_selection_combobox.get()
    Selected_Day=Day_selection_combobox.get()
    return load_data(Selected_City,Selected_Month,Selected_Day)

Submit_button=tkinter.Button(frame,text='Submit',command= selection)
Submit_button.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='news',padx=20,pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

**Proof:**

The error below is the proof that the function is running without any issue.

```
    df=pd.read_csv() ### Here  insert the file location !!!!
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: read_csv() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath_or_buffer'
```

**Limitation:**

Since I don't have the `.csv` file I haven't entered data into this code through that.

Comment: Your code is setting the `Selected_XXX` variables when the script starts, not when the user submits.

Comment: Oh sorry about that I totally forgot to place it in a function, thx for pointing